# Why does the program only save some, but not all, of data to binary file?

Tags: c

After write data to the binary file, I changed the mode to "r" to read the file. The `name` of `who` is correct, but `color` and `education` are empty. `Age` is returned as a large integer number, which is I guess the address of the variable. So, what is wrong here?

Update: The answer of Retired Ninja and Thornkey almost solve my problem. The rest is if input of `age` is 26, but not other numbers, the program will not write correct input to file. Anyone know what is wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLEN 100


typedef struct Person{
    char name[MAXLEN];
    int age;
    char color[MAXLEN];
    char education[MAXLEN];

} Person;

void create_person(Person *who){
    printf("name: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", who->name);
    printf("age: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &(who->age));
    printf("color: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", who->color);
    printf("education: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", who->education);


}

void print_record(Person *who){
    printf("name: %s\n", who->name);
    printf("age: %d\n", who->age);
    printf("color: %s\n", who->color);
    printf("education: %s\n", who->education);

}

void load_db(FILE *fp, Person *who){
    int result = fread(who, sizeof(who), 1, fp);
    if(!result)
        //printf("result%d", result);
        printf("cannot load database");
}


FILE *connect_db (char *file_name, char *mode, Person *who){
    FILE *fp = (FILE *)malloc(sizeof(100));
    // open stream and load database from the file
    if(strcmp(mode, "w") == 0){
        fp = fopen(file_name, mode);
        //load_db(conn); // load data from file
    }else if(strcmp(mode, "r") == 0){
        fp = fopen (file_name, mode);
        load_db(fp, who); // load data from file
    }else{
        printf("incorrect mode");

    }

    return fp;

}

// save database to file
int save_db (FILE *fp, Person *who){

        int result = fwrite(who, sizeof(who), 1, fp);

        if(result){

            return 0; // successfully save db

        }
        printf("cannot save db");




}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char answer[MAXLEN];


    Person person;
    Person *who = &person;
    FILE *fp;
    create_person(who);

    fp = connect_db("record2.dat", "w", who);

    save_db(fp, who);
    print_record(who);
    free(fp);
    fclose(fp);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(who)` is the size of a pointer, probably 4 or 8.  You may have meant `sizeof(*who)` or `sizeof(Person)`.  `sizeof(100)` is the size of an int.  You don't need to malloc memory for a file pointer anyway, just assign it from `fopen`.

Comment: `free(fp); fclose(fp);` is undefined behavior (although not the cause of your bug).

Comment: @Retired Ninja: I change all the code as you said but the result is still the same.

Comment: @Anonymous: so how I can fix the code?

Comment: When you fopen fp, you should not be malloc-ing to fp, this leads to a memory leak. It's probably the reason you incorrectly do free(fp); close(fp).

Comment: @rhubarbdog: I remove malloc and free but it did not work out. But I changed fread to fscanf as Thornkey advised, and it works. Thanks guys!

Comment: In load_db and save_db after the read/write you should be comparing result to sizeof(*who). fread/fwrite returns the number of bytes read or less than 0 on complete error.  The only success condition after fread/fwrite is result==sizeof(*who)

Comment: Age 26 probably means you have a byte containing control-Z (ASCII code 26 decimal, 032 octal, 0x1A hex).  If a program on Windows or DOS reads a text file (not a binary file) and encounters control-Z, that will be interpreted as EOF and everything after that will be ignored.  If the file is read in a binary mode, then control-Z is just another byte in the file. Unix does not treat control-Z — or any other byte, come to that — specially.  A file has a length and EOF occurs when you've read to the end of the file (slightly over-simplifying, but not enough to matter).

Comment: @rhubarbdog: `fread()` returns the number of _elements_ successfully read, not the number of bytes. The size of an element is specified by the second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fread() reads individual bytes. You want to read in numbers which you have printf'd.

Your files will look like this:

```
name: Samuel Thornkey
age: 24
colour: blue
education: PHD in computer science
```

But when you use fread, the program directly reads bytes from the file and fills them into the record. Your person will then contain:

```
char name[MAXLEN]: first MAXLEN characters i.e. "name: Samuel Thornkey\n  age: 24\ncolour: blue\n" or something similar
int age: the rest of the characters, encoded as bytes, hence very large number
char color[MAXLEN]: empty
char education[MAXLEN]: empty
```

Instead, use fscanf:

```
fscanf(fp,"name:%s ",&who->name);
fscanf(fp,"age:%d ",&who->age);
```

and so on.

Comment: The issue was that the wrong size was used with `fread`/`fwrite`.  With that fixed the file will not look like what you've described and the advice, although good for parsing data from a text file, doesn't apply to the binary format being written.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to be this:

```
free(fp);
fclose(fp);
```

You are not permitted to free memory that wasn't given to you by `malloc` (or `realloc`).

And, yes, you may *think* you've allocated it inside `connect_db` but (1) that's totally unnecessary, and (2) you overwrite the pointer when you call `fopen`.

In addition, `save_db` is using the size of the `who` *pointer* which will most likely not be the same as the type it points to.

So, make the following changes:

- get rid of the call to `malloc`, just use `FILE *fp;` within `connect_db`.
- get rid of the `free(fp)` within `main`.
- in `save_db`, use `sizeof(Person)` rather than `sizeof(who)`.

Comment: I remove free(fp), but result is still the same.

Comment: @PMH, there's another issue with your `fwrite` call which I've included in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fixed version that may be of some help to you.  It successfully fills in a Person, prints it, and writes it to the file.  Then it reads the data back from the file into a different Person and prints it.

The structure is similar to what you had, but I made all the reading/writing explicit so you'd see the steps.  In general it isn't a good idea to have functions that perform extra duties you might not always want.  I also made `create_person` require no input for faster testing.  Your input code looked okay, I just didn't want to type it every time.

One thing to keep in mind, if you plan to write binary data to a file you should open the file in binary mode ("wb" or "rb") to avoid line ending translation on systems that perform that on text files.

You might also consider that a file written on one system may not be readable on a different system if the size of the Person structure changes due to different alignment or `int` being a different size.  Probably not an issue for you, but if it becomes one you might look into a different serialization scheme.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLEN 100
typedef struct Person
{
    char name[MAXLEN];
    int age;
    char color[MAXLEN];
    char education[MAXLEN];

} Person;

void create_person(Person *who)
{
    strcpy(who->name, "Fred Smith");
    who->age = 21;
    strcpy(who->color, "Red");
    strcpy(who->education, "Some School");
}

void print_record(Person *who)
{
    printf("name: %s\n", who->name);
    printf("age: %d\n", who->age);
    printf("color: %s\n", who->color);
    printf("education: %s\n", who->education);
}

void load_db(FILE *fp, Person *who)
{
    int result = fread(who, sizeof(*who), 1, fp);
    if(!result)
        printf("cannot load database");
}

FILE *connect_db(char *file_name, char *mode, Person *who)
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    if(strcmp(mode, "w") == 0)
    {
        fp = fopen(file_name, mode);
    }
    else if(strcmp(mode, "r") == 0)
    {
        fp = fopen(file_name, mode);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("incorrect mode");
    }
    return fp;
}

int save_db(FILE *fp, Person *who)
{
    int result = fwrite(who, sizeof(*who), 1, fp);
    if(result)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    printf("cannot save db");
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    Person who1;
    Person who2;
    create_person(&who1);
    print_record(&who1);

    fp = connect_db("record2.dat", "w", &who1);
    save_db(fp, &who1);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = connect_db("record2.dat", "r", &who2);
    load_db(fp, &who2);
    print_record(&who1);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for all the advice.

Comment: Hey man, I just found that if age is 26, but not other number, the program will not write correct input to the file. Do you know what is wrong here?

Comment: 26 is the `EOF` character on Windows.  That's one of the reasons you want to open the file in binary mode when you read and write binary data.  Change the `fopen` calls to look like `fp = fopen(file_name, "wb");` and `fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");` and see how that works.